# python telnet client via socket with tab completion

Tags: python, sockets, telnet

I have this example:

```
# s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# s.settimeout(2)

# connect to remote host via s.connect((host, port))


while 1:
    socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = select.select(socket_list , [], [])

    for sock in read_sockets:
        #incoming message from remote server
        if sock == s:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            if not data :
                print 'Connection closed'
                sys.exit()
            else :
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)

        #user entered a message
        else :
            msg = sys.stdin.readline()
            s.send(msg)
```

It works, but uncomfortably without bash completion.

How can I add "tab" autocompletion, like this:

```
user@test:~$ pyt       <<< (PRESS TAB)
user@test:~$ python    <<< Auto complete
```

Answer (score 1):

The autocomplete feature comes from your shell program (e.g. bash) and when you start your script it is no longer available because the terminal interacts with your program.

I am afraid you will have to implement your own completion.

Comment: Default telnet command (like a "telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX") works with tab completion. Has this command his own completion?

Comment: This is because you are in your shell (bash) when you type "telnet xxx.xxx...", but when you have started the python interpreter your terminal interacts with it - not the shell (bash).